Returning to App in Portrait Mode from Third Party API ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE - Kotlin
I have an app which operates strictly in portrait mode. I call the camera app via ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE. The user is able to take pictures in landscape mode and if they click the "OK" button in the camera app while in landscape mode, it tries to return to my app in landscape mode and thus, causes a crash. If they take the picture in landscape mode but click the "OK" button while in portrait, the return to the app works as it should. I've tried forcing it back to portrait by calling requireActivity().requestedOrientation= ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT in onResume but it's still crashing. I've also tried placing the finish() call for the CameraActivity within a Runnable to delay it, thinking this might give enough time for my app to return to portrait, but it also did not work. Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Examine the stack trace in Logcat. If you do not understand what it is telling you, consider adding a [mcve] with the stack trace and the code that is crashing.
